# Meaning of "is irrespective of"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I am reading a contract which is plain english except from a sentence which says:

> [your] right to be paid for work done on this contract is
>   irrespective if [agency] is paid by the [client]

My brain wants to read this as saying

> "your right to be paid is irrespective of whether the agency is paid by the client"

to the point where it looks like a typographical error. Yet this is a contract which has been heavily vetted so I don't think it is an error.

Please no "ask a lawyer" answers or comments as my question is about the english language and I am specifically inquiring whether the sentence is correct english and whether it is equivalent of saying "is irrespective of".

Comment: I agree with you. Hope someone can point to a conclusive source

Comment: This is "officially" flagged as a typo here:  http://www.finedictionary.com/Irrespective%20of.html.  Heavily vetted and poorly vetted are different things. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen the phrase used that way, nor does it make sense when used in that fashion. Googling the phrase "irrespective if" doesn't yield any meaningful results. As such, I think that **your interpretation is likely correct**, e.g., that you have a right to be paid for your work whether the agency is paid by the client or not. Mistakes sometimes make it through documents that are heavily edited - it's not *uncommon* to see erratum provided for text books or scientific articles that have been heavily peer-reviewed.

Personally, I'd bring it up with the agency and ask for a clarification.

Answer (score 1):

This sentence phrase is agrammatical in standard English: [your] right to be paid for work done on this contract is irrespective if [agency] is paid by the [client]

I bang this stuff out all the time (as a translator), and I daresay it is not work done "on this contract", which would mean doing work writing the contract, but "work done or performed under this contract". 
"Irrespective if" is agrammatical in English; it should be: irrespective of whether the agency is paid by its client.

So, acceptable, standard English phrasing would be:
your right to be paid for work done under this contract is unrelated to whether [name of agency] is paid by [name of client].

Personally, I would not write: is + irrespective of. In any event, "irrespective if" is a mistake, heavy vetting or not.

Comment: most definitely you are correct that it means "doing work under the terms of the contract" as the contract covers my professional services and I am not a lawyer. when you say you "bang this out all the time" do you mean that you see such mistake all the time on things you are asked to translate from English?

Comment: To bang something out is an old Fleet Street term (journalism) meaning to write an article on a manual typewriter. Therefore, it means to write an article or piece. I said bang out because I consider translation a form of writing...you can say doing work under the terms of the contract but under this contract means the same thing. Shorter is better, I think...

Comment: i meant were you making mistakes or correcting them. you say you wouldn't write that line in your answer but that contradicts your statement that you bang them out. so which is it?

Comment: to bang something out means to write something. I "write" translations and therefore I know that one says "to do or perform work under a contract" is what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm no lawyer but with only the context you've presented I see ambiguity.

> Your right to be paid is irrespective when [agency] is paid by the client"

That's another way to take it.  Take it this way and it leaves you wondering where irrespective is qualified and what happens to your right to be paid when the agency isn't paid by the client.  That isn't a grammatical flaw.  It's a loophole.

There maybe context or legal tradition that overrides this but if you can't find it don't believe the contract until someone can make it clear to you.

Comment: Shouldn't there be an *irrespective of*?

Comment: @NVZ, you might be right, you might be wrong.  I stand by my answer, irrespective.  See what I did there? :)  BTW, Ngram Viewer says 'of' is about 1000 times more popular than 'if' but 'irrespective if' does have usage.  So while it makes our brains scream I can't say it's grammatically wrong.

Comment: Well, uhm.. You might be right, you might be wrong. I stand by my comment, _nonetheless_. ;)

Comment: @NVZ hehe, ok.  But you see how irrespective was qualified by the previous sentance?  That's what I meant by context.  With the right context the question might have a clear meaning.  As it is now it certainly doesn't.  But grammar doesn't guarantee meaning.

Answer (score 0):

I understand it as:
Your right to be paid stays intact, whether the client pays the agency or not...in other words, you will be paid (or will be owed compensation by the agency) once you have completed your work, if the agency collects money from third parties or not, (the collection part doesn't concern you).